# Number of months between two dates for each year in r

Tags: r, date, monthcalendar, data-management

I'm working with data that looks like this:

```
name       start_date        end_date
 A         1993-06-25       1993-11-04
 B         2003-12-12       2004-07-20
 C         1997-06-11       2000-11-27
 D         1990-06-29       1992-07-02
```

I want to count up the number of months in each year that the names span.

So that the data looks like this:

```
name  year number_months
A     1993    5
B     2003    1
B     2004    7
C     1997    6
C     1998   12
C     1999   12
C     2000   11
D     1990    6
D     1991   12
D     1992    7
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
name <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
start_date <- as.Date(c("1993-06-25", "2003-12-12", "1997-06-11", "1990-06-29"))
end_date <- as.Date(c("1993-11-04", "2004-07-20", "2000-11-27", "1992-07-02"))

df <- data.frame(name, start_date, end_date)
```

Comment: Because I'm counting 2003-12-12  as including 1 month in 2003 and the rest, 7 months in 2004

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Across all the names, I want to know how many months each name spans for each year it covers.

Comment: Ok, got it.  I think the easiest approach would be to do a `seq` from that start_date to 'end_date' by 'year',

Comment: @akrun, Dont worry. I'm going to amend the question and make it clearer.

Comment: just make a table of the years `table(format(seq(df[2, 2], df[2, 3], by = 'months'), '%Y'))`

Comment: Nice, that gets me closer!

Comment: Extending rawr solution `do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y, z) cbind(name = z, stack(table(format(seq(x, y, by = 'months'), '%Y')))), df$start_date, df$end_date, df$name))`. Please check the numbers as there is some discrepancy with the numbers

Comment: @SharifAmlani I have a doubt with the 'name' 'C" '1997-06-01' do you count the months including the 6th month or from the next month onwards

Comment: Including the month is perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
   transmute(name,  out = map2(start_date, end_date,
     ~ seq(.x, .y, by = 'months') %>% 
           year %>%
           table %>%
           enframe(name = 'year', value = 'number_months'))) %>% 
   unnest(c(out))
```

---

Or another option with `interval`

```
df %>% 
     transmute(name,  out = map2(start_date, end_date,
          ~ tibble(date = seq(.x, .y, by = 'months'), year = year(date)) %>%
               group_by(year) %>%
               summarise(number_months = interval(floor_date(first(date), 'month'), 
                   ceiling_date(last(date), 'month')) %/% months(1)) )) %>%
     unnest(c(out))
```

---

Or in `base R` (extending @rawr's solution)

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y, z) 
 cbind(name = z, stack(table(format(seq(x, y, by = 'months'), 
  '%Y')))), df$start_date, df$end_date, df$name))
```

Or as @rawr commented, replacing the `stack` with `data.frame` can be used as well

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y, z) 
     cbind(name = z, data.frame(table(format(seq(x, y, by = 'months'), 
       '%Y')))), df$start_date, df$end_date, df$name))
```

Comment: i almost beat you to it in the comments :} if you use `data.frame` instead of `stack`, the column order is fixed